# Prove that a vector space $V = \mathbb{F}^3_2$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ has 16 subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$V$ also has 256 subsets and I do not know how.

Comment: Hiint: How many $0$ dimensional spaces does it have? How many $1$-dimensional spaces? How many $2$-dimensional spaces? How many $3$-dimensional spaces? To count $1$-dim spaces, perhaps find a basis?

Comment: Welcome to math.se. [Here are some guidelines on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Answer (score 2):

$V$ has one subspace of dimension 0 - the zero space.

The subspaces of $V$ of dimension 1 correspond to non-zero elements of $V$. There are $2^3$ elements of $V$, one of which is 0. So there are $7$ dimension-1 subspaces.

Note that every subspace $U \subseteq V$ has an orthogonal complement $U^\perp = \{v \in V : \forall u \in U (u \cdot v = 0)\}$. By the rank-nullity theorem, $dim(U) + dim(U^\perp) = dim(V)$, so $dim(U^\perp) = dim(V) - dim(U)$. Therefore, $dim((U^\perp)^\perp) = dim(U)$. And $U$ is a subspace of $(U^\perp)^\perp$. Then $U = (U^\perp)^\perp$.

Therefore, we see that the subspaces of $V$ of dimension 2 correspond to the subspaces of $V$ of dimension 1 in a bijective way (the bijeciton $U \mapsto U^\perp$). There are thus 7 of them.

Similarly, the subspaces of $V$ of dimension 3 correspond exactly to subspaces of $V$ of dimension 0. There is thus 1 of them.

This is a total of 16.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let us prove that it has $256$ subsets. As $V=\mathbb{F}_2^{3}$ its cardinality is equal to $8$. Hence it has $2^8=256$ subsets (as $2^n$ is the number of subsets of a $n$-set). Now lets prove that it has $16$ subspaces.
The elements of $V$ are : $(0,0,0);(0,0,1);(0,1,0);(1,0,0);(1,1,0);(1,0,1);(0,1,1);(1,1,1)$.
In addition we know that any subspaces of $V$ must contain $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$. As $dim(V)=3$ the dimension of any subspace $W$ of $V$ is $\le 3$.
So you just have to consider the different cases $dim(W)=1,2$ or $3$.
Hope this will help you. If you have any more questions dont hesitate to comment.
Hubert